# Or function only looks at first value

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
    Dim difficulty As Integer 'Sets difficulty as integer
    If txtBack.Visible = True Or btnDisplay.Enabled = False Then 'if back of the flashcard is visible and if the start button has been clicked
        If Integer.TryParse(TxtDifficulty.Text, difficulty) AndAlso difficulty >= 1 AndAlso difficulty <= 3 Then 'If diffiuclty is between 1 and 3
            Dim front = txtFront.Text 'Defines front as variable which is equal to txtfront.text
            UpdateDifficultyLevel(front, difficulty) 'Calls subroutine
            MsgBox("Difficulty updated succesfully") 'outputs messagebox saying difficulty has been updated succesfully
        Else 'If user input is not an integer
            MsgBox("Please enter a number between 1 and 3") ' tells user that the difficulty must be a number
        End If
    Else 'If back of the flashcard is not visible and is start button has not been clicked
        MsgBox("Please display the flashcard") 'Tells user to display flashcard.
    End If
End Sub
```

This code is supposed to check if txtback.visible = true or btndisplay.enabled = false then runs the appropriate code. However only the txtback.visible works. How would I get the code to also check if btndisplay.enabled = false?

Comment: What do you mean exactly when you say "only the txtback.visible works"? With your code, the `UpdateDifficulty` function inside the if-block will be called when `txtBack` is visible or `btnDisplay` is disabled (or both!). In other words: that function should *not* be called only when `txtBack` is invisible *and* `btnDisplay` is enabled.

Comment: yeah that's what I thought but for some reason it doesnt work if btnDisplay = false

Comment: With your code, when `btnDisplay.Enabled = False` the entire condition of the if-block will evaluate to true, so the UpdateDifficulty function should be called regardless of the value of txtBack.Visible. You could set a breakpoint on the if-statement (the third line of your code) and check during debugging the actual values of `txtBack.Visible` and `btnDisplay.Enabled`.

Comment: I would also like to give an off-topic comment to your code. In an if-statement, you check for a condition that evaluates to a boolean value. When the condition evaluates to true, it executes the if-block, otherwise it executes the else-block. The properties `txtBack.Visible` and `btnDisplay.Enabled` are already of boolean type, so you can just use them directly. The condition `txtBack.Visible = True Or btnDisplay.Enabled = False` can be perfectly simplified to `txtBack.Visible Or Not btnDisplay.Enabled`. ;)

Comment: Prefer `OrElse` over `Or`. No need to check the second condition here if the first one is `True`.

Comment: In contrast to VB6, which evaluated all expressions of a boolean expression _before_ the boolean operator was considered, VB.NET implemented what is known as [sort-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you want to use Or? The comment on that if statement says:
"if condition1 AND condition2 are true, then...". In that case, if you want both to be checked and evaluated as true just do

```
If txtBack.Visible = True And btnDisplay.Enabled = False Then
```